# Scanf with char

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

Why is that without `getchar` functions wrong? Why `scanf("%c",&slovo);` doesnt get char?

```
int a,b;
char slovo;

scanf("%d",&a);
getchar();

scanf("%c",&slovo);

scanf("%d",&b);
getchar();
```

Comment: Why is it that some people don't read manuals and think they can guess their way around C? This is exactly what happens... I hope you can learn from your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Because scanf ignores linebreaks and the symbol stays in the input buffer until the next function that read from the buffer starts.